# It would be... vs. it could be

Tags: meaning

When my doorbell rings and I think it is my friend at the door, what should I say?

1. It **would** be my friend at the door.
2. It **could** be my friend at the door.

What is the difference between those two versions?

Answer (score 7):

The difference is if you use *It would be my friend* that means you are expecting him and him only. 
If you say *It could be my friend* it implies that you are expecting your friend but you think it might be someone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

More natural in terms of quite confident expectation is the use of "should":

> [Star Trek Generations: A Novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xwLE1iN2rs0C&q=%22that%20should%20be%20him%22&dq=%22that%20should%20be%20him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=McQSVcnhCImXgwTN54GQAw&redir_esc=y) - Page 16 Jeanne M. Dillard, ‎Rick
>   Berman, ‎Ronald D. Moore - 1994 - ‎Snippet view - ‎More editions
>
> But Chekov never got the chance to explain things to Scott; a sonic
>   boom, followed almost instantly by another, distracted him. "**That
>   should be him now**," he said.